# Как указать команде find_pakage по какому адресу искать библиотеку в cmake?

Tags: c++, cmake, библиотеки, сборка

Как указать команде find_pakage по какому адресу искать библиотеку в cmake? Проблема в том, что библbотека установлена не в usr/local и find_package не знает где ее искать, как указать путь к директории, содержащей библиотеку для find_package?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7029371/how-to-point-cmake-at-specific-directory-for-library

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Есть три способа указать CMake на место, где искать библиотеку через `find_package`:

1. Добавить в переменную `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH` **установочную директорию** библиотеки.
   Например, если библиотека ставилась с установочным префиксом `/home/me/install`, то можно либо вызывать `cmake` с дополнительным параметром:

   ```
   cmake -DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=/home/me/install <... остальные параметры cmake>
   ```

   либо установить переменную среды перед вызовом `cmake`:

   ```
   export CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=/home/me/install
   cmake <...>
   ```
2. Найти **конфигурационный файл** библиотеки XXX (`XXXConfig.cmake` или `xxx-config.cmake`) и указать его **директорию** в переменной `XXX_DIR`. Например, если конфигурационный файл библиотеки Foo имеет полный путь `/home/me/install/share/cmake/FooConfig.cmake`, то можно либо передать `cmake` дополнительный параметр:

   ```
   cmake -DFoo_DIR=/home/me/install/share/cmake <...>
   ```

   либо установить аналогичную переменную среды перед вызовом `cmake`:

   ```
   export Foo_DIR=/home/me/install/share/cmake
   cmake <...>
   ```
3. Установить переменную `XXX_ROOT` равной **установочной директории** библиотеки. Например, если библиотека Foo ставилась с установочным префиксом `/home/me/install`, то можно либо вызывать `cmake` с дополнительным параметром:

   ```
   cmake -DFoo_ROOT=/home/me/install <...>
   ```

   либо установить переменную среды перед вызовом `cmake`:

   ```
   export Foo_ROOT=/home/me/install
   cmake
   ```

Способ с установкой переменной `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH` достаточно **универсален**: он влияет сразу на все библиотеки, которые ищутся, а также влияет на поиск библиотек с использованием "Find" скриптов. (Остальные способы влияют только на поиск "Config" скриптов).

Установкой переменной `XXX_DIR` можно повлиять на поиск **избирательно**, только для одной библиотеки. Важно учесть, что директория `XXX_DIR` должна напрямую содержать "Config" скрипт и не всегда совпадает с установочной директорией для библиотеки.

Установка переменной `XXX_ROOT` также влияет на поиск **избирательно**, только для одной библиотеки. При этом эта переменная должна содержать именно установочную директорию (не обязательно искать "Config" файл в ней).
Но для проектов, нацеленных на версию CMake 3.11 и ниже, могут выдаваться предупреждения: переменная [XXX_ROOT](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/PackageName_ROOT.html) появилась только в версии CMake 3.12.